# ServiceStack CredentialAuthProvider with more than User/Password

Tags: servicestack

I want to use a custom auth provider, but I don't see how I can make the standard Auth stuff  handle more that user and password as parameters.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you want to do, if you want to create your own Custom auth provider by inheriting from CredentialsAuthProvider, you can access different request params via the `IHttpRequest` object:

```
public virtual bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, 
    string userName, string password)
{
    var httpReq = authService.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>();
    var fromQueryString = httpRequest.QueryString["CustomField"];
    var fromPostData = httpRequest.FormData["CustomField"];
    var fromEither = httpRequest.GetParam("CustomField"); //Ext method
}
```

Here are some other related questions and answers that show different ways to customize ServiceStack's built-in Auth:

- [How can I extend ServiceStack Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117469/how-can-i-extend-servicestack-authentication)
- [Populating IAuthSession with data from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594048/populating-iauthsession-with-data-from-the-database)

Comment: Thanks Demis.  I may just ditch the Custom Auth altogether.  My needs are pretty unique and the concept of user/password doesn't real make sense to my model and shoe-horning CustomAuth in seems like a hack.  Real problem is I have been struggling with keep a session token every "session-required" service needs to pass.  First thought was cookie (seems insecure), next up was Authentication header which seems like I am putting too heavy a requirement on the client (and locks me in to http), so likely I am going to add the token as an interface to every DTO.